# Add line segments to histogram in ggplot2 with radar coordinates

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

I am trying to make a polar histogram in ggplot2 with annotation lines which are not radial lines.

The simple approach with `coord_polar` gives curved lines:

```
library(ggplot2)

d = data.frame(x=rep(seq(0, 350, 10), times=1:36))
lines = data.frame(x = c(40, 90, 150, 220, 270), 
y = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20), 
xend = c(115, 165, 225, 295, 345), 
yend = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5))

ggplot(d, aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 10) + 
  geom_segment(data = lines, 
               aes(x, y, xend = xend, yend = yend), 
               color = 'red') + 
  coord_polar() + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, 360))
```

[image: Polar histogram with curved segments]

Second try uses `coord_radar`, from various sources on StackOverflow and mail lists:

```
coord_radar <- function (theta = "x", start = 0, direction = 1) 
{
 theta <- match.arg(theta, c("x", "y"))
 r <- if (theta == "x") 
        "y"
      else "x"
 ggproto("CoordRadar", CoordPolar, theta = theta, r = r, start = start, 
      direction = sign(direction),
      is_linear = function(coord) TRUE)
}

ggplot(d, aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 10) + 
  geom_segment(data = lines, 
               aes(x, y, xend = xend, yend = yend), 
               color = 'red') + 
  coord_radar()
```

This fails completely:

[image: coord_radar fail]

I can get the lines to draw if I use grouped lines instead of segments:

```
lines2 = data.frame(x = c(40, 115, 90, 165, 150, 225, 220, 295, 270, 345, 330, 45), 
y = c(20, 5, 20, 5, 20, 5, 20, 5, 20, 5, 20, 5), 
group = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6))

ggplot(lines2, aes(x, y, group = group)) + 
  geom_line(color = 'red') + 
  coord_radar() + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 36)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 360))
```

[image: coord_radar using geom_line]

but I still need the histogram...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56146393/8449629) on the `geom_segment` portion. The long and short of it is this: the `draw_panel` function of the ggproto Geom objects behind `geom_segment` / `geom_histogram` have two different methods of drawing the respective geoms, depending on whether the ggplot object's coordinate system is linear or non-linear.

`coord_polar` is non-linear (we can run `CoordPolar$is_linear()` to confirm this), so the geoms are drawn correctly using the methods associated with non-linear coordinate systems. `coord_radar` is linear, so the linear methods are used instead, and cause havoc.

We can get around this by defining tweaked versions of relevant Geoms that only include the non-linear methods, and `geom_*` functions that call on them instead of the original Geoms.

`geom_segment2`:

```
GeomSegment2 <- ggproto("GeomSegment2",
                        GeomSegment,
                        draw_panel = function (data, panel_params, coord, arrow = NULL,
                                               arrow.fill = NULL, lineend = "butt", 
                                               linejoin = "round", na.rm = FALSE) {
                          data <- remove_missing(data, na.rm = na.rm, 
                                                 c("x", "y", "xend", "yend", "linetype", 
                                                   "size", "shape"), 
                                                 name = "geom_segment")                          
                          if (ggplot2:::empty(data)) 
                            return(zeroGrob())
                          # remove option for linear coordinate system
                          data$group <- 1:nrow(data)
                          starts <- subset(data, select = c(-xend, -yend))
                          ends <- plyr::rename(subset(data, select = c(-x, -y)), 
                                               c(xend = "x", yend = "y"), 
                                               warn_missing = FALSE)
                          pieces <- rbind(starts, ends)
                          pieces <- pieces[order(pieces$group), ]
                          GeomPath$draw_panel(pieces, panel_params, coord, arrow = arrow, 
                                              lineend = lineend)
                        })

geom_segment2 <- function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity", 
                           position = "identity", ..., arrow = NULL, arrow.fill = NULL, 
                           lineend = "butt", linejoin = "round", na.rm = FALSE, 
                           show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE) {
  layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, 
        geom = GeomSegment2, # instead of GeomSegment
        position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
        params = list(arrow = arrow, arrow.fill = arrow.fill, 
                      lineend = lineend, linejoin = linejoin, na.rm = na.rm, 
                      ...))
}
```

`geom_histogram2`:

```
library(grid)

GeomBar2 <- ggproto("GeomBar2",
                    GeomBar,
                    draw_panel = function (self, data, panel_params, coord, 
                                           width = NULL) {
                      # copy over GeomRect's draw_panel function for the non-linear portion
                      aesthetics <- setdiff(names(data), 
                                            c("x", "y", "xmin", "xmax", "ymin", "ymax"))
                      polys <- plyr::alply(data, 1, function(row) {
                        poly <- ggplot2:::rect_to_poly(row$xmin, row$xmax, row$ymin, row$ymax)
                        aes <- as.data.frame(row[aesthetics], 
                                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[rep(1, 5), ]
                        GeomPolygon$draw_panel(cbind(poly, aes), panel_params, coord)
                      })
                      ggplot2:::ggname("bar", do.call("grobTree", polys))
                    })

geom_histogram2 <- function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "bin", 
                             position = "stack", ..., binwidth = NULL, 
                             bins = NULL, na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, 
                             inherit.aes = TRUE) {
  layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, 
        geom = GeomBar2, # instead of GeomBar
        position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
        params = list(binwidth = binwidth, bins = bins, na.rm = na.rm, 
                      pad = FALSE, ...))
}
```

Usage:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram2(binwidth = 10) + 
  geom_segment2(data = lines, 
                aes(x, y, xend = xend, yend = yend), 
                color = 'red') + 
  coord_radar() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 360))
```

[image: plot]