# ggRadar highlight top values in radar

Tags: r, ggplot2, radar-chart

Hi everyone I am making a a radar plot and I want to highlight the two highest values in the factors or levels. Highlight in this case is to make the text of the top tree values bold

```
require(ggplot2)
require(ggiraph)
require(plyr)
require(reshape2)
require(moonBook)
require(sjmisc)
ggRadar(iris,aes(x=c(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Petal.Length,Petal.Width)))
```

an example can be like this

[image]

thank you

Comment: What quantity is shown on the radial axis? For example,  `Sepal.Width` takes a value around 0.44. How is that value calculated?

Comment: It comes directly from the data, I am assuming that is not a calculation just to highlight the top three values. In my real world application the data comes verbatim from a survey.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But in order to highlight certain top categories, we need to understand how these values are being calculated. `iris` contains 150 measurements of 4 variables (categories). Somehow `ggRadar` shows a single value for every category, and you like to highlight the top three categories. How are these single values calculated?

Comment: Hi Maurits in this case should be the highest value of the species for each variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a step-by-step example of how to highlight specific categories in a radar plot. I don't really see the point of all these extra dependencies (`ggRadar` etc.), as it's pretty straightforward to draw a radar plot in `ggplot2` directly using polar coordinates.

1. First, let's generate some sample data. According to OPs comments and his example based on the `iris` dataset, we select the maximal value for every variable (from `Sepal.Length`, `Sepal.Width`, `Petal.Length`, `Petal.Width`); we then store the result in a long `tibble` for plotting.

   ```r
   library(purrr)
   library(dplyr)
   library(tidyr)
   df <- iris %>% select(-Species) %>% map_df(max) %>% pivot_longer(everything())
   df
   #    # A tibble: 4 x 2
   #  name         value
   #  <chr>        <dbl>
   #1 Sepal.Length   7.9
   #2 Sepal.Width    4.4
   #3 Petal.Length   6.9
   #4 Petal.Width    2.5
   ```
2. Next, we make use of a custom `coord_radar` function (thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56146393/r-how-to-combine-straight-lines-of-polygon-and-line-segments-with-polar-coordin)), that is centred around `coord_polar` and ensures that polygon lines in a polar plot are straight lines rather than curved arcs.

   ```r
   coord_radar <- function (theta = "x", start = - pi / 2, direction = 1) {
       theta <- match.arg(theta, c("x", "y"))
       r <- if (theta == "x") "y" else "x"
       ggproto(
           "CordRadar", CoordPolar, theta = theta, r = r, start = start,
           direction = sign(direction),
           is_linear = function(coord) TRUE)
   }
   ```
3. We now create a new column `df$face` that is `"bold"` for the top 3 variables (ranked by decreasing `value`) and `"plain"` otherwise. We also need to make sure that `factor` levels of our categories are sorted by row number (otherwise `name` and `face` won't necessarily match later).

   ```r
   df <- df %>%
       mutate(
           rnk = rank(-value),
           face = if_else(rnk < 4, "bold", "plain"),
           name = factor(name, levels = unique(name)))
   ```
4. We can now draw the plot

   ```r
   library(ggplot2)
   ggplot(df, aes(name, value, group = 1)) +
       geom_polygon(fill = "red", colour = "red", alpha = 0.4) +
       geom_point(colour = "red") +
       coord_radar() +
       ylim(0, 10) +
       theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = df$face))
   ```

   [image]

   Note that this gives a warning, which I choose to ignore here, as we explicitly make use of the vectorised `element_text` option.

   > Warning message:
   > Vectorized input to `element_text()` is not officially supported.
   > Results may be unexpected or may change in future versions of ggplot2.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to identify the highest values you wish to highlight, and put them in a dataframe.  Then use `geom_richtext()` to highlight.